# How to show that $f(x) \cdot [J_f (x) * u] = 0$, where $f: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^q$, and f is differentiable s.t $|f(x)| =1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

In the book of *The Elements of Real Analysis* by Bartle, at page 247, it is asked that

> If $f$ is differentiable on an open subset $D \subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}^p$ and has values in $\mathbb{R}^q$ such that $|f(x)| = 1$
>   for $x\in D$, then $$f(x) \cdot Df(x)(u) = 0 \quad for \quad x\in D, u
>  \in \mathbb{R}^p.$$ Note: in Bartle's notation $Df(x)(u) = J_f(x) *
>  u$, where $J$ is the jacobin of $f$ at $x \in D$.

I have tried the following:

$$f(x) \cdot [J_f (x) * u]  = f(x) \cdot [\sum_{k = 1}^p J_{i, k} u_k]_{i,1} = \sum_{l = 1, k=1}^p f_l(x) J_{l, k} u_k \\
= \sum_{l = 1}^p f_l(x) [\nabla f_l(x) \cdot u]$$
but stuck in here, so my questions are that

i-) How can we continue from the point where I left ?

ii-) How can we show the desired result alternatively ?

**Edit:**

**Further answers are also welcomed, since there might be more intuitive diverse solutions to this question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule.

Let $g:\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}\RR^p\to\RR$ be $g(x) = \|x\|$. Note that $g$ is differentiable away from the origin, with derivative 
$$D_xg(u)= \sum_{i=1}^p \frac{x_iu_i}{g(x)}=\frac{x\cdot u}{g(x)}.$$
If $\|f(x)\|=1$, then $$D_x (g\circ f)(u) = (D_{f(x)}g\circ D_x f)(u)= 0,$$
but then, noting that $g(f(x))=1$ by assumption,
$$0=(D_{f(x)}g) (D_xf(u))= \frac{f(x)\cdot D_xf(u)}{g(f(x))}=f(x)\cdot D_xf(u),$$
as desired.

Also sorry, out of habit, I've used the notation $D_xf := Df(x)$

Comment: In the first equation, shouldn't the result be $\frac{1 \cdot u}{g(x)}$ ?

Comment: No, you can check that the $j$th partial derivative of $\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}$ is $\frac{x_j}{\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}}$.

Comment: Plus, why is the second equation equal to zero ?

Comment: Because the derivative of a constant is 0.

Comment: $g$ is not a constant function and neither $f$, so ? **Edit:** But the composition is constant, right .

Comment: $g\circ f$ is constant by assumption

Comment: as in, by assumption $g\circ f =1$.

Comment: Yes, to the edit

Comment: Thanks a lot both for your answer and further responses.

Comment: Np, glad it was helpful :)